# How to make Picasso start displaying image part without download completed

Tags: android, android-imageview, picasso, android-image

Currently I use this Java code:

```
Picasso.with(mainAct)
        .load("http://IMAGE_URL.png")
        .into((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.background_image));
```

Xml:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/image_card"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="188dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <RelativeLayout
     android:id="@+id/bgImage_relative"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent">

       <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/background_image"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        ...
  </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

But it **only display the image after download completed**.

The image URL is a bit slow and some of the images keep blank for > 10 seconds.

How can I make it **partially display image like how web browser do** ?

Comment: if you don't find the the solution for partially display image like how web. you  can use Picasso with placeholder image or display a progress on image. then user will know that image is loading

Comment: This might help, but it's not exactly what you are looking for, so I will put here in comment. Picasso has these two methods `.load(url).placeholder(R.drawable.user_placeholder).error(R.drawable.user_placeholder_error)` that can be used to display images while it downloads (placeholder) or if an error occurr (error).

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I just found out even WebView not able to do a partially display if i try to load image url from WebView.